# Process builder is not able to update previous value of a field

Tags: apex, process-builder

Hi friends i got a requirement like to update opportunity stage to price quote and with out changing the probability value whenever any quote is generated for the quote.

So,i create a process in quote object and updating values.But i am unable to update previous value of probability.It's updating probability related to stage.

For reference:

[image: Process]

Please guide me in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

> There is dependency between stage and probability, once select stage, probability will be auto changed, even user has modified the probability as other value before, but it will be also rewrite with default value link to stage.

Though a knowledge article is available [Remove linkage between stage and probability](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187810&type=1), but I think that will not solve your purpose.

Comment: Ya i know @Santanu Boral but if i write workflow on opportunity level it's working fine.